# GWT memory buffer compared to session storage

Tags: html, gwt, local-storage, gxt

Working with GWT/GXT i like to speed-up my App with 'local-caching'.
I red about HTML5 session storage, but i was wondering why i shouldn't just use a memory buffer (a big hashmap with all the incoming data).

Whats the pitfall with the memory buffer compared to session storage?

Comment: Session storage survives page refresh and is shared between pages (tabs / windows). Use accordingly depending on needs.

Comment: Before you start optimizing your app, you should exactly know what the bottleneck is. There are many possible parts of your app which can slow it down: The response time of your backend, client-side rendering (e.g. to big data grids), deserialization of (complex) objects, complex calculations in javascript and so on. A shot in the dark may in the end be counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as what Thomas Broyer detailed in his comment, the pitfall for using a Map or any similar kind of data structure to save data is that all your data will be lost on page refresh.

If this is not a concern for your given scenario, I don't see any issue using Map/List or anything like that.

In the Errai framework we use a lot of `@ApplicationScoped` beans to hold data across the whole application, for example the currently logged in user, the latest loaded data from server etc.